# How to manage compile time dependencies in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Trying to avoid the use of jargon, so that I don't get misinterpreted.
Here is the scenario, My project requires a jar in order to get compiled(let say x.jar). My project get once compiled gets converted into a WAR file, which gets deployed somewhere.

Now I want x.jar just to be there for my project to compile and it should not be packed(or part of) inside WAR file.


How can I do this in Maven ? should I used dependency scope as "provided"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, as stated in the [Maven FAQs](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#scope-provided), the scope to use is `provided`,

> How do I prevent including JARs in WEB-INF/lib? I need a "compile only" scope!
>   The scope you should use for this is provided. This indicates to Maven that the dependency will be provided at run time by its container or the JDK, for example.
>
> Dependencies with this scope will not be passed on transitively, nor will they be bundled in an package such as a WAR, or included in the runtime classpath.

To quickly try it out, you can use

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

to generate a "toy webapp" project, add a dependency to your project and set it to `<scope>provided</scope>`.